# Express - How to redirect parameter value from app.post method to app.get method

Tags: node.js, express, neo4j, ejs

I am very new to nodejs and expressjs.

I am creating a very simple and one page nodejs application which will take a number from user and based on that value will return number of rows from Neo4j Database.

For that I am using one single app.js file where both app.post() and app.get() methods are there. I am trying to use the app.post() method's value, which is "Rows" into the app.get('/post/output/') method, but I am unable to do that.

Below is the code that I could able to write:

```
app.get('/', function(req,res,next){
res.render('index1');
});

app.post('/post', function(req,res,next){
var Rows = req.body.Rows;
res.redirect('/post/output/');
});

app.get('/post/output/',function(req,res,next){
console.log(Rows);
session
.run('MATCH (N:NewsMedia) RETURN N ORDER BY N.Audience DESC LIMIT 
{nameparam}',{nameparam:Rows})
.then(function(result){
    var newsmedia = []; 
    result.records.forEach(function(record){
        newsmedia.push({
            name: record._fields[0].properties.name,
            size: record._fields[0].properties.Audience
        });
    });
    res.render('index',{
        NewsMedia: newsmedia
    }); 
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
})
```

Comment: It is generally the client's job to take info from one POST and use it in a subsequent GET request.  Since there are potentially lots of different clients, a server can't store that type of state in a plain variable like you are trying to do.  It could store it in a session that was specific to that client or in a cookie, but it would be better if the client managed it entirely since it's really the client that knows what it will do next and with what data.

Comment: I think I got your point @jfriend00 , but i do not know how to implement it.

Comment: You'd have to show us the client code for us to help with that.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have added the index.ejs file and also how the home  page looks like.

Comment: Why don't you just do `res.send(someContentHere)` from within the `.post()`?  I don't see where your client code does the GET that you're asking about to understand what the real problem is.

Comment: app.post()  has the variable "Name", which stores the value that user will be giving, now i want to use that same variable inside app.get() method in .run() line.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood how a form post works.  The browser sends the form data to the server as a POST.  Your server parses that data and then returns a response back to the browser which the browser then displays.  You seem to be missing the second part.  There is no GET involved in a form post.

Comment: So, what can i do over here? I need to use the form data that is coming from browser as a POST, in my Neo4j database query, and the output of that query i want to send back to the browser.

Comment: So, put that code inside the POST handler and return the result from the POST with `res.send()`.  You've shown no reason to even have that `.get()` handler.  It appears you just want to move all that code into the POST handler and return the response from their.  Then, the browser will display that result.

Comment: hi @jfriend00 I have edited what I have done so far, but i am still unable to achieve what I want to, which is to send the "Rows" parameter from the POST method to app.get('/post/output/') method

Comment: I already explained to you that you should just render from your POST handler where you already have the data you want.  There is no need to redirect and then render as that just complicates things.  Is there a reason you are ignoring that guidance and not even commenting on it?  Can't really help you if we give you advice and you ignore it and don't even comment on it.  It's like we're having a one-way conversation here which isn't very productive.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00  thank you so much, it is resolved now, and I am so sorry i can see i made you unhappy. I shouldve just simply followed you.

Comment: Not unhappy, just puzzled why you don't even respond when I offer you ways to solve your problem.

Comment: yes my bad @jfriend00
thanks again, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be no reason to do a redirect here.  If you were going to do a redirect, there are three ways to pass data to a specific redirect:

1. With a query parameter in the URL you redirect to.
2. By setting data in a cookie
3. By storing data in a server-side session (which is tied to a session cookie)

That said, it seem to me that you can just skip the redirect and put the rendering code inside the POST operation.  The browser will render whatever data you send back from a form post and will show it in the browser:

```
app.get('/', function(req,res,next){
    res.render('index1');
});

app.post('/post', function(req,res,next){
    var Rows = req.body.Rows;
    console.log(Rows);
    session.run('MATCH (N:NewsMedia) RETURN N ORDER BY N.Audience DESC LIMIT {nameparam}',{nameparam:Rows})
      .then(function(result){
        var newsmedia = []; 
        result.records.forEach(function(record){
            newsmedia.push({
                name: record._fields[0].properties.name,
                size: record._fields[0].properties.Audience
            });
        });
        res.render('index',{
            NewsMedia: newsmedia
        }); 
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});
```

You do NOT want to save state between requests in module level variables or global variables because those will be accessed by all requests from all users which means if two users are in the process of the same redirect, their data will clobber each other and one user's data would show up in the other user's browser.  That's a recipe for disaster.  User-specific state has to be shared from one request to another in one of the ways listed above.

Answer (score -1):

You have to redirect from post to GET if you are not calling GET from client.Also you need not have global variable Name.

```
app.post('/', function(req,res,next){
Name = req.body.fName;
   console.log(Name);
  res.redirect('/register')
})
app.get('/',function(req,res,next){
 console.log(Name);
   next();
});
app.get('/',function(req,res){
 console.log(Name);
session
    .run('MATCH (N:NewsMedia) RETURN N ORDER BY N.Audience DESC LIMIT {nameparam}',{nameparam:Name})
    .then(function(result){
        var newsmedia = []; 
        result.records.forEach(function(record){
            newsmedia.push({
                name: record._fields[0].properties.name,
                size: record._fields[0].properties.Audience
            });
        });
        res.render('index',{
            NewsMedia: newsmedia
        }); 
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
})
```

Comment: hi @dev9 I have edited what I have done so far, but i am still unable to achieve what I want to, which is to send the "Rows" parameter from the POST method to app.get('/post/output/') method.

Comment: Using a higher scoped variable to track state from one request to another like this is completely WRONG.  This assumes that only one user is ever using this server at once.  As soon as you have two users doing this at hte same time, this absolutely will not work properly.  This is completely wrong.

Comment: @Sankar - See my previous comment to this answer and also see my answer.  The technique in this answer is simply wrong server design and will lead to one user's data getting mixed up with other user's data.  You can't write servers this way.

Comment: Yes @jfriend00 i followed your answer and got the output, thanks for explaining this to me.