# How to use variables from app.post in order to find and match them to database in app.get?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Hey I'm trying to use variables from my app.post in app.get but I'm getting an error that variables are not defined.

basically, I'm receiving data from API calls (when the user is submitting an input in a form),
then filtering the data to relevant data I want to display and store this data in the mongoose database.

now the problem is when I'm trying to find data in app.get from my DB and equal it to the variables from the app.post (in order to render the data on a relevant page [using ejs]) then I'm getting the error >>> **asin is not define**

what am I missing here? please see my code below

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
Asin.findOne({asinId:asin},function(err){
if(!err){
 res.render("home");
}
});
});


app.post("/", function(req, res) {

//SOME API LOGIC//

https.get(url,options,function(response) {

//DATA RCIEVED//

response.on("end",function(){
const asinData = JSON.parse(data);
const asin = asinData.products[0].asin;
const parentAsin = asinData.products[0].parentAsin;
const category = asinData.products[0].categoryTree[1].name;
const subCategory = asinData.products[0].categoryTree[0].name;
const fbaFee = asinData.products[0].fbaFees.pickAndPackFee/100;

const newAsin = new Asin({
asinId:asin,
parentAsinId:parentAsin,
categoryId:category,
subCategoryId:subCategory,
feesId:fbaFee
});

newAsin.save(function(err){
 if(!err){
   res.redirect("/");
 }else{
   console.log(err);
 }
 });
```

Comment: I found the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/48982102/21289112

Answer (score 0):

Well, all I had to do is create an empty var for each const before the app.get, that way I could use the variable in both routs.